# Arduino Bluetooth value intrepetation

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to build a bluetooth-controlled tracked vehicle, but the code seems to misintrepet the values it gets from the HC-05 bluetooth-module. When going forward, the controller is supposed to send "2" and the code is supposed to change the value of the integer "dir" (for direction) to 2. However, it receives "128" three times when pressing the button down and a "0" and a "0" when releasing the button. Here's the part of the code that receives the signal and determines the direction (based on this [tutorial](http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut7_1.php)):

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) 
   {
    dir = Serial.read(); //Reads Bluetooth signals value
    Serial.println(dir); 
   }/*else{
    dir = 0;
   }*/

   delay(10);
```

And here's the full code:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor left(3);
AF_DCMotor right(4);

int dir = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);

  left.setSpeed(255);
  right.setSpeed(255);
}

void still(){
  left.run(RELEASE);
  right.run(RELEASE);
}

void forward(){
  left.run(FORWARD);
  right.run(FORWARD);
}

void backward(){
  left.run(BACKWARD);
  right.run(BACKWARD);
}

void clockwise(){
  left.run(FORWARD);
  right.run(BACKWARD);
}

void counterClock(){
  left.run(BACKWARD);
  right.run(FORWARD);
}

void leftforth(){
  left.run(RELEASE);
  right.run(FORWARD);
}

void rightforth(){
  left.run(FORWARD);
  right.run(RELEASE);
}

void leftback(){
  left.run(RELEASE);
  right.run(BACKWARD);
}

void rightback(){
  left.run(BACKWARD);
  right.run(RELEASE);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
   {
    dir = Serial.read(); //Reads Bluetooth signals value
    Serial.println(dir); 
   }/*else{
    dir = 0;
   }*/

   delay(10);

  if(dir == '0'){
    still();
  }else if(dir == '1'){
    leftforth();
  }else if(dir == '2'){
    forward();
  }else if(dir == '3'){
    rightforth();
  }else if(dir == '4'){
    counterClock();
  }else if(dir == '5'){
    clockwise();
  }else if(dir == '6'){
    leftback();
  }else if(dir == '7'){
    backward();
  }else if(dir == '8'){
    rightback();
  }
}
```